# How to limit the onclick to just the H2?

Tags: javascript, css-transitions

http://jsfiddle.net/dragontheory/CxNnB/

Need to be able to limit the onclick to just the H2. Otherwise clicking on the inner content closes it.

Changing the:

```
$('article').on('click', function() {
```

to

```
$('h2').on('click', function() {
```

doesn't help since it's not a parent?

Thanks.

Original: http://paintincode.blogspot.com/2012/04/css3-transition-slideup-box-take-2.html
http://jsfiddle.net/cpkDg/

Answer (score 2):

It wont work since `.content` is not a child of `this`, which is the `<h2>` element in this context. You can traverse to `<h2>`'s parent element by using `$(this).parent()`:

```
$('h2').on('click', function() {
    slide($('.content', $(this).parent()));
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CxNnB/3/)

Comment: Wow! That was fast! Thank you. I knew it had something to do with the parent child relationship not matching up.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('h2').on('click', function() {
    slide($(this).next('.content_w').find('.content'));
});
```

or

```
$('h2').on('click', function() {
    slide($(this).parent().find('.content'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That was fast! All three of these solutions worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('h2').on('click', function() {
  slide($(this).parent().find('.content')); 
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cpkDg/178/)

Comment: I knew it had something to do with the parent/child relationship not matching up. I know where I am coming the next time I have a simple question. Thank you very much. You guys are realy fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it was the `h2` that was clicked

```
$('article').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('h2')){
        slide($('.content', this));
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/CxNnB/11/)

Comment: Why not `$('article').on('click', 'h2', function ( e ) {...});`?

Comment: Why use delegation?, also all the answers bind to h2

Comment: If you are going to bind to article, you might as well delegate it.

Comment: @Trevor: Didn't knew that `on` provided a way to delegate events. Should check the API more often.

Comment: Yes. It stems from the deprecated `delegate` method. Quite useful. :)

Comment: TIL. Musa or @Trevor, put it in an answer and you get an upvote!